# R Shiny display checkboxGroupInput horizontally

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

How to display `checkboxGroupInput` horizontally (inline block) with R shiny?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId="test", label="Test", choices=1:4),
tags$style(type="text/css", HTML("#test>*{float: left; margin-right: 15px; height: 20px;} #test {height: 20px;}"))
```

Or directly edit a `css` file, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/EMQV8NbA3MI

**EDIT**

Since `shiny 0.10.0`, you can use the `inline` argument for horizontal layout :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId="test", label="Test", choices=1:4, inline = TRUE)
)
server <- function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have use the `inline` argument for horizontal layout of my checkbox, but how to alin all the box ?

Comment: @Victorp, I had requirement on use of checkboxGroupInput for usage of filter and displaying items for selected variable in filter. It would help me a lot if you could have a look and suggest. Thank you !! Link to the post is    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187194/shiny-dynamic-filter-variable-selection-and-display-of-variable-values-for-sel#