# Aligning Checkboxes in Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, checkbox, shiny

This is my first post. 
I am trying to align checkboxes in shiny using checkboxGroupInput but have no backgroung in css whatsoever. I have tried a lot of the codes I found online that seemes to work for other scenarios but I guess my case is a little different.

here is the relevant code from inside my fluidpage() and I will post a picture of the result.

```
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                        .multicol .shiny-options-group{
                        -webkit-column-count: 5; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                        -moz-column-count: 5;    /* Firefox */
                        column-count: 5;
                        -moz-column-fill: balanced;
                        -column-fill: balanced;
                        }
                        .checkbox{
                        margin-top: 0px !important;
                        -webkit-margin-after: 0px !important; 
                        }
                        "))),
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align checkBoxGroupInput vertically and horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742191/align-checkboxgroupinput-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  I answered that question and it looks like to code is cut and pasted from that question.  But that means there is now way to tell what exactly is going on.  Could you please post a minimum working example that demonstrates the error?